# What causes X or What does cause X?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

> *What causes coral bleaching ?*

> *What does cause coral bleaching ?*

What is the difference?? Which is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE THIS: ***What causes*** coral bleaching?
NOT THIS: <del>*What does cause coral bleaching?*</del>

---

This is one of the most common errors made by learners. Presumably, it usually happens *after* learning auxiliary verbs (*be*, *do*, *have*) and the subject-verb-inversion in Yes/No questions.

How can we deal with it?

Here is a good rule of thumb: keep in mind that ***What*** and ***Who*** questions can ask for the **subject** or the **object** of the verb. And it depends on what we ask about.

- If the **What** (or **Who**) question asks for the **object** of the verb, we invert the subject and the auxiliary verb like we do in Yes/No questions. For example,

> > *"**What is** this?" "This is **a book**."* -- (*a book* is the object of the verb *is*)
> >     *"**What did** you say?" "I said, **'Hello'**."* -- (*'Hello'* is the object of the verb *said*)
> >     *"**Who will** you hire?" "I'll hire **John**."* -- (*John* is the object of the verb *will hire*)

- If the **What** (or **Who**) question asks for the **subject** of the verb (and thus the subject of the sentence, when the sentence is a simple sentence), we DO NOT invert the subject and the auxiliary verb. In other words, we use the normal word order: the same word order as we use in declarative sentences. For example,

> > *"**What** fell on him?" "**A book** fell on him."* -- (*A book* is the subject of the the verb *fell*)
> >     *"**Who** owns this house?" "**Jake** owns this house."* -- (*Jake* is the subject of the verb *owns*)

---

In your sentence, you need ***What causes coral bleaching?***, because you ask for the subject of the verb *causes* (so an answer could be something like: ***The rise of sea temperatures causes coral bleaching***, where *The rise of sea temperatures* is the subject of the verb *causes*).

We don't normally use the other alternative, *"<del>What does cause coral bleaching?</del>"*. (It could be used the same way we could use *I do like it*.) Avoid using it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, It was so useful for me.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

Questions  with "who/what" as subject don't use to do. In the following examples "who1/what1" signifies subject case.

- Who1 told you this? -Not: Who1 did tell you this?
- What1 causes the Earth to move round the sun? - Not: What1 does the Earth cause to move round the sun?

So only "What1 causes coral bleaching?" is correct.

Comment: But it's perfectly correct to say "What does this mean?" Also... why are there 1s after "who" and "what"?

Comment: @Catija  What (object case) does this (subject case) mean? When who/what is object  case you need to do. I explained above who1/what1 means subject case. As in English who/what can be subject or object case I  sometimes use who1 for nominative/subject case and who 4 for accusative/object case to make things clearer. I use the traditional order of Latin cases 1 nom, 2 gen, 3 dat, 4 acc.

Comment: rogermue, Thank you for your explanation. It was helpful