# "Which website <were you/you were> trying to open?"

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, word-order

What is the correct way to ask this?

> Which website were you trying to open?

or

> Which website you were trying to open?

Comment: You can use the same guideline I posted in [What causes X or What does cause X?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/69231/3281). Basically, ask yourself whether the answer is the subject of the verb or not, and (not invert or) invert subject-verb in your *Wh*-question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. **You** **were** trying to open which website?
> 2. Which website **were** **you** trying to open?

If we move the *wh-* word to the beginning of the question, we need to change round the subject and the auxiliary verb. If we don't, the question is ungrammatical:

- <del>*Which website you were trying to open?*</del> [ungrammatical]

Comment: Though note that "Please tell us *which website you were trying to open*:" would be fine.

Comment: @JacobRaihle That's right because that sentence isn't a question! ;-)

Comment: Also "You were trying to open which website?" has a very different meaning than "Which website were you trying to open?".

Comment: @DRF I agree that it has a different flavour, but does it have a different meaning?

Comment: I would say yes. You certainly can't use it in the same circumstances, the first sentence IMO assumes you have already been told which website the person was trying to open and you either forgot, or you are expressing disbelief over what you heard. When I read it I pretty much heard that "which" in bold in my head. On the other hand "Which website were you trying to open?" is a perfectly ordinary question just asking for your input.

Comment: @DRF Yes, the information packaging constraints are extremely different for sure. I'm not sure it always has to be an echo question though. When I was filling in a form with one of my students at reception yesterday, the guy there asked him *And you are from which county?* :)

Comment: @Araucaria True. That sounds quite normal though I would have expected this to be in relation to something you were filling in on the form. Maybe you were filling in the county he came from? But you are certainly right that it's not as clear cut as I made it sound.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the correct way of asking.

> Which website were you trying to open?

This is because the sequence of subject, verb and object matter for correct grammatical construction.

For more on this, refer: http://wps.ablongman.com/long_longman_ohb_1/27/7023/1797910.cw/-/1797917/index.html